# submit form with out spring form tags

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I am developing a simple app in spring mvc without using spring form tags, currently my work is done by using below code but for understanding purpose I am asking this question.
I have two backing beans classes which I have bound to one html `<form>` tag which is not possible in spring form tags.

**bean 1**

```
   public class Interim {
    private int interimId;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private int interimCategory;
    // setter n getter
    }
```

**bean 2**

```
    public class Bcr {
    private int bcrId;
    private BigDecimal cashAmount;
    private int interimCategory;
    }
```

**html form**

```
<form action="/interim" method="get">
<input type="text" name="amount" />
<input type="text" name="cashAmount" />
<input type="text" name="interimCategory" />
<button type="submit" name="Month" > month </button>
</from>
```

**spring controller**

```
@Controller
public TestController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/interim", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String interimInit(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("interim",new Interim());
        map.addAttribute("bcr",new Bcr());
        return "interim";
    }

/// on form submit
@RequestMapping(value = "/interim", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "Month")
    public String getMonthlyInterim(@ModelAttribute("bcr") Bcr b,ModelMap
            modelMap,@ModelAttribute("interim") Interim in) {



}
```

When I submit the form spring mvc set interimCategory in both beans,

1. How to tell spring not to set interimCategory of Bcr bean?
2. Is this good way to create an html form in spring ?

Comment: You're using POST method on the form, however, you have only GET methods on your controller

Comment: ops edited, thanks ;-)

Comment: your action on the form is "/test" but you don't have a method with RequestMethod of "/test"

Comment: for some reason i paste all code from original but form i wrote my own

Comment: You can't have 2 methods with the same path & the same method (GET)

Comment: I can not understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Spring form tag, you can choose to send your form using JQuery Ajax + send your data inside an HTTP body using POST method, that the body of that HTTP message will be JSON message.

Then you can use the @RequestBody annotation to bind that json to your variable on the controller.

Comment: then how can i get value of `cashAmount` in `getMonthlyInterim(@ModelAttribute("interim") Interim in)` method ?